# Splitting a line from a file into tokens in java

Tags: java, split, line, token

I am currently reading the file token by token and I want to read a whole line first and then split it up into tokens instead.  This is part of the code where I am reading by token:

```
public void getNextToken(){
     String temp = input.next();        

     if(temp.equals("$")){
         nextToken = Symbols.ENDOFFILE;
     }
     else if(temp.equals("a")){
         nextToken = Symbols.IDENT;
     }
     else if(temp.equals(";")){
         nextToken = Symbols.SEMICOLON;
     }
     else if(temp.equals("const")){
         nextToken = Symbols.CONSTANT;
```

Comment: Why do you want to change that? It will make the code less clear for little gain.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileName);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s");
    //do what you want to do with the tokens
}
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

See [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

The Class ctor I am using:

```
StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)
```

An example:

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test", "$a; ");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/) you can find bunch of examples.

Answer (score 0):

try so:

```
BuffereReader reader = new BufferedReader(**YourInputStream**);
String line = reader.readLine();

String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");
```